# Can I upgrade ath9k driver to ath10k in Xubuntu 18.04?

Tags: wireless, upgrade, xubuntu, atheros, ath9k

I have a kernel version 4.15.0-76-generic in Xubuntu 18.04, WiFi card is Qualcomm Atheros AR9565 Rev:1 and uses **ath9k** driver, can I upgrade this driver to **ath10k** with no problems? thanks, vladi

Comment: No. Don't do it. See answer from _pilot6_ below.

Comment: You could upgrade the hardware to a chipset that uses ath10k

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to "upgrade" `ath9k` to `ath10k` because these are two different drivers for different hardware.

Both modules are included in the 4.15 Linux kernel.